# Apache spark (pyspark), how to replace a value in a column of a row with another value from same column from a different row

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Apache spark (pyspark), how to replace a value in a column of a row with another value from same column from a different row

```
df1.filter(F.col('LAST_NAME') == 'Maltster').withColumn("ANNUAL_HOUSEHOLD_INCOME", df1.filter(F.col('LAST_NAME') == 'Attiwill').select(F.col('ANNUAL_HOUSEHOLD_INCOME'))[0]).show()
```

I am trying to replace the 'ANNUAL_HOUSEHOLD_INCOME' value in the row with LAST_NAME=Malster with the 'ANNUAL_HOUSEHOLD_INCOME' value in the row with LAST_NAME=Attiwill.

For ex:

```
Before running the code, the table looks like:
+---------+-----------------------+
|LAST_NAME|ANNUAL_HOUSEHOLD_INCOME|                               
+---------+-----------------------+
|Maltster |20000                  |
|Attiwill |100000                 |
+---------+-----------------------+

After running the code the table should look like:

+---------+-----------------------+
|LAST_NAME|ANNUAL_HOUSEHOLD_INCOME|                               
+---------+-----------------------+
|Maltster |100000                 |
|Attiwill |100000                 |
+---------+-----------------------+
```

But when I run the above code the value is not being overwritten

Comment: it is better to explain the problem statement with 2 to 3 columns and with sample data to get help

Comment: @Suresh I have made changes as requested

Comment: @vrn You can use the `.when().otherwise()`

Comment: @Jonathan, we can use .when().otherwise(). But I am not sure what condition to use in when statement. I tried using, the boolean True as condition, but spark is throwing an error, informing that it has to be a column.

Comment: @Jonathan even if I do add a condition `df1.filter(F.col('LAST_NAME') == 'Maltster').withColumn("ANNUAL_HOUSEHOLD_INCOME", F.when(F.col('ANNUAL_HOUSEHOLD_INCOME').isNotNull(), df1.filter(F.col('LAST_NAME') == 'Attiwill').select(F.col('ANNUAL_HOUSEHOLD_INCOME'))[0]))`, the value is not changed

Answer (score 1):

I think you should reread the docs, it should be:

```
df.withColumn('ANNUAL_HOUSEHOLD_INCOME', F.when(F.col('LAST_NAME')=='Maltster', F.lit(100000)).otherwise(F.col('ANNUAL_HOUSEHOLD_INCOME')))
```

Comment: you have used a literal (F.lit(100000)), but what I am trying to accomplish is to get a value from a different row which matches a condition (Ex: LAST_NAME='Attiwill') and then update the value in row with `LAST_NAME='Maltster'`

Comment: The requirement being how do I get the value in a cell based on some condition. Ex: row with LAST_NAME='Attiwill' and Column_Name='ANNUAL_HOUSEHOLD_INCOME'

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Jonathan's answer, the below code will give the correct output:

```
df1.withColumn('ANNUAL_HOUSEHOLD_INCOME', F.when(F.col('LAST_NAME')=='Maltster', df1.filter(F.col('LAST_NAME') == 'Attiwill').select(F.col('ANNUAL_HOUSEHOLD_INCOME')).collect()[0][0]).otherwise(F.col('ANNUAL_HOUSEHOLD_INCOME')))
```